# Zend Framework: How to assemble proper url when in directory

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, redirect

How can I force Zend Router to assemble proper urls when the site is running under a directory?

Here's what I mean:

```
$this->view->url(array('controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action'), null, true)
```

Would usually return something like `/controller/action` where in my case it returns `/tbogdanov/brandenburg/controller/action`, because the site is running in the directory `/tbogdanov/brandenburg`.

That is actually a good URL and I have no problem with it. However, when passed to `$this->_redirect()` the redirector just prepends the directory again. So, the final redirect url now looks like this: `/tbogdanov/brandenburg/tbogdanov/brandenburg/controller/action`.

Now, that's incorrect.

Is there any setting I might be missing? It seems zend is aware it is running in a directory/sub-directory, but still at some point, it ignores it. I am looking for a good generalized solution, no `str_replace` ones!

Also the method should work properly even if at some point the project is moved in the root directory (which will happen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `_redirect()` configures the options. Add `array('prependBase' => false)` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

try using a redirector object where you have more options for the link creation

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector

```
    // Redirect to 'my-action' of 'my-controller' in the current
    // module, using the params param1 => test and param2 => test2
    $this->_redirector->gotoSimple('my-action',
                                   'my-controller',
                                   null,
                                   array('param1' => 'test',
                                         'param2' => 'test2'
                                         )
                                   );
```